# What app can I use for making android tablet into a second screen for windows?

Tags: windows, android, touchscreen

What app can I use for making android tablet into a second screen for windows?   Tried spacedesk but it seems to disconnect a lot.

Also what would be nice is if it could mirror just a portion of my screen because of screen size difference.